# npm run dev mix doesn't work in laravel 9

Tags: npm, laravel-9

I have a fresh laravel 9 project
I want to create an auth system with laravel command by using

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and also

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

after that I did

```
npm install

npm run dev
```

but rather that opening a mix development to generate css styles of auth pages it gave me this output in terminal

[npm run dev image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPlFL.png)

and the page style is being like this

[Page styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYcTy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem

the problem was in the **package.json** file

package.json was like this:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.25",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "sass": "^1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "vite": "^2.9.11"
    }
}
```

As you can see the dev in script was applied to vite,

```
    "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
    }
```

I just modified vite to mix and run

> npm install again

and the problem was resolve and tyles of my login page generated successfully

[Styles result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi7yf.png)

Comment: Can you please share your changes?

Comment: @PabloLopez I post another solution with more details and a better way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** - **## Better Solution:**

**Installing Laravel/ui**

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

**Install Bootstrap Auth Scaffold**

```
 php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

**In Vite.config file**

**import path by adding this at top:**

```
import path from 'path';
```

**after plugins add this:**

```
resole: {
  alias: {
     '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_module/bootstrap'),
  } 
}
```

final result of vite config file will be like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resole: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_module/bootstrap'),
        }
    }
});
```

**From resources/js/app.js  - add these lines**

```
import '../sass/app.scss';

import * as boostrap from 'bootstrap'
```

**Final Result of resources/js/app.js will be like this**

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../sass/app.scss';
import * as boostrap from 'bootstrap'
```

**Final Step is to change styles and script to @vite directive in resources/view/layouts/app.blade.php**

change any css or js files from this type

```
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to @vite directive type

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/css/app.css'])
```

Make sure you already have those files before trying to include it, otherwise vite will cause an error.